# Using python to read cells and score rows in a folder of csv files with multiple rows

Tags: python, csv

I'm a newb with multi-layered problem.

I am trying to score each record in each CSV file in a folder based on whether a keyword is present in one column.

Each folder has five CSV files

Each CSV file contains roughly 20 records.

Each record has five columns: title, link, author, date, and body.

I want to read the body, count the number of time "potato" appears, and add the score to the end of the record.

I got excited when I succeeded at adapting [this code][1] from Ben Welsh that can read and score whole CSV files.

Here, the keyword being counted is "hasse,"

```
import re, os

path = "./nietzsche"
freddys_library = os.listdir(path)
hate = open("hate.txt", "w")

for book in freddys_library:
    file = os.path.join(path, book)
    text = open(file, "r")
    hit_count = 0
    for line in text:
        if re.match("(.*)(hasse|hasst)(.*)", line):
            hit_count = hit_count + 1
            print >>  hate, book + "|" + line,

    print book + " => " + str(hit_count)
    text.close()
```

This got me one score per file, but I need one score per row per file.

Thanks to anyone offering help.

Comment: If the code below doesn't suit your purposes, just say how you'd like it modified and I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: this code reads in all files with .csv extension in the specified directory, then splits each of those files into a series of rows (all of which are contained in the list object splitCsv), then counts the instances of the searchTerm of interest (defined in line 4) in each row. It then creates a new file called "foundHits.txt", in which it writes the total number of instances of the searchTerm in a given row, followed by a tab, followed by the contents of the row in which the search term occurs (or doesn't):

```
import os
import glob

searchTerm = "China"

#create output file in which we'll store all of the data that contains the word of interest
out = open("foundHits.txt", "w")

hitCount = 0

for csv in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Douglas\\Desktop\\potato\\*.csv"):
    openCsv = open(csv, "r")
    readCsv = openCsv.read()

    #split each row into a string within the list "splitCsv"
    splitCsv = readCsv.split("\n")

    #for each row in the current csv
    for row in splitCsv:

        #split each row on the phrase "PM ET", which separates your metadata from the text data you want to scan
        splitRow = row.split("PM ET")

        #determine whether the string of interest appears in what I take to be the data of interest

        #use this if condition in order to prevent the script from breaking if it encounters a row that doesn't contain "PM ET"
        if len(splitRow) > 1:

            #split each time you encounter that word
            splitOnTerm = splitRow[1].split(searchTerm)

            searchTermInstances = len(splitOnTerm) - 1

            #print row for review
            out.write(str(searchTermInstances) + "\t" + str(row) + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi duhaime, thanks for the help. I thought this would work, but it seems that the column split isn't working. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Rank", line 21, in <module>
    if "potato" in splitRow[4]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: cont'd -- It looks like the split created a list of the row containing the headers ['"title"', '"author"',...] and then treated this as a single column. ???

Comment: Are you reading in .csv files? Can you edit your question and post a snippet of your data? Are you sure your data has 5 columns (or more)?

Comment: Also, the split is recognizing commas within the quoted text. So "16,000 potatoes" becomes "16, 000 potatoes".

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3Pc5WQogO_MZkhBcUUtcVFpakk&usp=sharing -- here's the link to the data. Let me know if you have any trouble getting it. Use whatever keyword you like to test.

Comment: Going into excel to reformat adds another step that I am trying to avoid. I tried shortening your code to search by row instead of by column in row, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Hey duhaime - Sorry I didn't see your previous post 'potentially simple solution.' The row by row search should work. Can you post the code? I tried to adapt but only got scores by file.

Comment: I edited my code above. Does this accomplish what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to be of help